# How do I reset ggplot2 theme_gray() back to default settings?

Tags: r, ggplot2

*R version 3.4.3 and ggplot2 version 2.2.1*

I open a fresh R Studio session with nothing in my global environment. I issue two commands. This is the output.

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_get()$panel.grid.minor

    List of 6
     $ colour       : chr "white"
     $ size         : num 0.25
     $ linetype     : NULL
     $ lineend      : NULL
     $ arrow        : logi FALSE
     $ inherit.blank: logi TRUE
     - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "element_line" "element"
```

It's my understanding ggplot theme settings do not carry over sessions. It's also my understanding that the `$ size : num 0.25` line item above is supposed to be `rel(0.5)` by default, not `num 0.25`. **How did this setting get changed and how do I reset all theme_gray() settings back to default?** Here's my grid.major settings for what it's worth. They may be screwed up as well.

```
List of 6
 $ colour       : chr "white"
 $ size         : NULL
 $ linetype     : NULL
 $ lineend      : NULL
 $ arrow        : logi FALSE
 $ inherit.blank: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "element_line" "element"
```

Comment: You can always reinstall the package if you're not sure

Comment: You're right, I have '0.5' for my size in `theme_grey()$panel.grid.minor`.  Any chance you've modified one of the start-up values, like those described [here](https://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html) or [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/Startup)?

Comment: When I run `ggplot2::theme_get()$panel.grid.minor$size`, I get `0.25`.  That's without having loaded the package previously in the session.  I'm using `ggplot2` version 2.2.1.

Comment: I reinstalled ggplot2 but that didn't help. No, I do not use an .Rprofile. Hmm... It seems that @wibeasley and @Nathan Werth have conflicting information. I'm not sure if the default value for `theme_grey()$panel.grid.minor` minor is *num 0.25* or *rel(0.5)*. The main issue is it's driving me bonkers having to specify the minor grid size on every ggplot I graph when I thought it should be 50% relative to the major grid size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output is correct. ggplot2 2.2.1 was released on Dec. 30, 2016. If we look at the source code from the most recent version before Dec. 30, 2016, we see [this line:](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/bd7d9d6e478f344f4064619bb4e7a1f926f2bea9/R/theme-defaults.r#L133)

```
panel.grid.minor =   element_line(colour = "white", size = 0.25),
```

In the [current development version,](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/3c9c504fdb2f2c6b70a98d5a02f6cdf2c8cc62c9/R/theme-defaults.r#L145) the same line looks like this:

```
panel.grid.minor =   element_line(size = rel(0.5)),
```

One way to solve the issue is to install the current development version of ggplot2. I've been using it for months and have made hundreds of figures with it. It works fine.

Comment: I took this advice and it worked on my Linux system. Strangely, my Windows system, with the current development version of ggplot2, still plots both major and minor gridlines with size 0.25. Should I attribute this to a bug?

Comment: Unlikely. It's more likely that the install somehow failed and you're still working with the older ggplot2.